# Call state module from within state module

Tags: python, salt-stack

I'm writing a [custom state module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/writing.html) with the purpose of creating a file in a given location with (partly) configurable content.

Basically I'm looking to shorten the following SLS (simplified for the purpose of this question, more complex in reality)...

```
/etc/foo/bar:
  file.managed:
    - contents: Hello World
```

...to this:

```
bar:
  my_module.foo:
    - message: World
```

Since this functionality is basically a more specialized version of the [`file.managed`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed) state, it would be useful for me to re-use the `file.managed` state in my custom state module.

**Is there any way to call the `file.managed` state module from my own state module?**

---

What I've tried already (unsuccesfully):

1. Importing `salt.states.file` and calling `salt.states.file.managed`:

   ```
   import salt.states.file

   def foo(name, message, **kwargs):
       return salt.states.file.managed(name='/etc/foo/%s' % name,
                                       contents='Hello %s' % message, 
                                       **kwargs)
   ```

   This results in an error message:

   ```
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/state.py", line 1626, in call
       **cdata['kwargs'])
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1492, in wrapper
       return f(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/states/my_module.py", line 14, in static_pod
       contents=yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False), **kwargs)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/states/file.py", line 1499, in managed
       mode = __salt__['config.manage_mode'](mode)
   NameError: global name '__salt__' is not defined
   ```
2. Using `__salt__['file.managed']`:

   ```
   def foo(name, message, **kwargs):
       return __salt__['file.managed'](name='/etc/foo/%s' % name,
                                       contents='Hello %s' % message, 
                                       **kwargs)
   ```

   Which also results in a (different) error message (which is unsurprising, as the documentation explicitly states that `__salt__` only contains *execution* modules, and not *state modules*):

   ```
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/state.py", line 1626, in call
       **cdata['kwargs'])
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1492, in wrapper
       return f(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/states/my_module.py", line 13, in static_pod
       return __salt__['file.managed'](name='/etc/foo/%s' % name,
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 900, in __getitem__
       func = super(LazyLoader, self).__getitem__(item)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/lazy.py", line 93, in __getitem__
       raise KeyError(key)
   KeyError: 'file.managed'
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using the [`state.single`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.single) execution module:

```
def foo(name, messsage):
    result = __salt__['state.single'](fun='file.managed',
                                      name='/etc/foo/%s' % name,
                                      contents='Hello %s' % message,
                                      test=__opts__['test'])
    return result.items()[0][1]
```

---

The `state.single` module returns a data structure like the following:

```
{
  'file_|-/etc/foo/bar_|-/etc/foo/bar_|-managed': {
    'comment': 'The file /etc/foo/bar is set to be changed',
    'name': '/etc/foo/bar',
    'start_time': '08:24:45.022518',
    'result': None,
    'duration': 18.019,
    '__run_num__': 0,
    'changes': {'diff': '...'}
  }
}
```

The inner object (everything under the `file_|-/etc/foo/bar_|-/etc/foo/bar_|-managed`) is what the `file.managed` module would return by itself, so you can re-use this value as your custom state's return value.