# Fetching updates every Salt highstate without failing highstate on error, instead reverting to defaults

Tags: devops, salt-stack

I have a systemd service `evil`, with state described in `init.sls`. This service requires the presence of a file `/etc/evil/wicked.txt`. This file pulls in updates from a python function `fetch_darkness` that contacts a server, the response of which changes very infrequently.

```
evil:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: {{ package_name }}
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/evil/wicked.txt
      - pkg: evil

/etc/evil/wicked.txt:
  file.managed:
    - contents: {{ salt.evil.fetch_darkness(grains['id'], pillar.node.hostname }} # this changes infrequently
    - show_changes: false
    - allow_empty: false
    - user: evil
    - group: evil
    - mode: 600
    - makedirs: true
    - require:
      - user: evil
    - watch_in:
      - service: evil
```

This creates a problem, because every highstate, it causes the service `evil` to be restarted, even if the actual contents of the file `/etc/evil/wicked.txt` haven't changed, which is 99% of the time.

So the next solution was creating a temporary file `/etc/evil/wicked-temp.txt` that wasn't watched by `evil`. `/etc/evil/wicked.txt` pulls its contents from `wicked-temp.txt` when that is changed, this way `evil` is only restarted when the file actually updates instead of every highstate:

```
evil:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: {{ package_name }}
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/evil/wicked.txt
      - pkg: evil

/etc/evil/wicked-temp.txt:
  file.managed:
    - contents: {{ salt.evil.fetch_darkness(grains['id'], pillar.node.hostname }} # this changes infrequently
    - show_changes: false
    - allow_empty: false
    - user: evil
    - group: evil
    - mode: 600
    - makedirs: true
    - require:
      - user: evil

/etc/evil/wicked.txt:
  file.managed:
    - source: /etc/evil/wicked-temp.txt
    - show_changes: false
    - allow_empty: false
    - user: evil
    - group: evil
    - mode: 600
    - makedirs: true
    - onchanges:
      - file: /etc/evil/wicked-temp.txt
    - require:
      - user: evil
    - watch_in:
      - service: evil

"rm /etc/evil/wicked-temp.txt":
  cmd.run:
    - onfail:
      - file: /etc/evil/wicked.txt
```

However, now the issue is, there are several servers that each get highstated, and there's many times that `fetch_darkness` isn't able to reach the main server, causing the highstate to fail as `wicked.txt`/`wicked-temp.txt` can't get populated.

This isn't great, because >99% of the time, the contents of the server response doesn't change. If `wicked.txt` doesn't exist, then sure, the highstate should fail. But if it does, then I'd like to keep using whatever already exists on the file `wicked.txt` and not have a failed highstate.

Is there a way to solve this problem:

1. Service must not restart unless file contents change
2. File must pull updates
3. Highstate must not fail if file already exists, but is unable to pull updates

EDIT: I should've mentioned that the file's contents do change every time. The file is a randomly generated key that is fetched from the central server, with a certain label attached, so something like `1-xxxxxxx`, or `2-yyyyyy`. However, `1-xxxxx` is identical to `1-zzzzzz`, even if the actual contents differ, which is why `evil` should not restart when `1-xxxxx` changes to `1-zzzzz`, but only when it changes to `2-yyyyyyy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have a custom module that does the fetch, why not create a custom state module that handles the rest? this way you can determine if the file actually changed, handle it when it does and correct for errors when the fetch doesn't work.

in the first example however it shouldn't do anything that triggers that the file changed unless something with the file actually is changing. you might want to double check what is changing in the file.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that the file's contents do change everytime. The file is a randomly generated key that is fetched from the central server, with a certain label attached, so something like `1-xxxxxxx`, or `2-yyyyyy`. However, `1-xxxxx` is identical to `1-zzzzzz`, even if the actual contents differ, which is why `evil` should not restart when `1-xxxxx` changes to `1-zzzzz`, but only when it changes to `2-yyyyyyy`.

Comment: I'm trying to work through the first part of your answer now, still getting the hang of salt so I'll think it through and update.

Comment: ok, that does change things. salt triggers the onchanges because contents change. regardless of what the program thinks is a change. if the contents are different then they were at the start then at the end file.managed will trigger a change so a evil state module is going to be required to get around the fact that different values really are the same thing. basically deeper logic around what the program is expecting beyond the default logic of a isn't b.

Comment: Could you please mention an example or pseudocode for the custom state module code? I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860976/call-state-module-from-within-state-module to get a sense of how it would work, but I'm not sure how to handle errors without failing highstate.

Comment: You don't need to use salt to save the file. you can use standard python open statements and the like. along the lines of https://gist.github.com/whytewolf/cca0632c9ae4ca4d3e1563dee95f3e45

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really helpful!